# Is there a way to alter an Orchard content shape's display type before placement and rendering happens?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

We are trying to implement a generic reusable paywall as a ContentPart in Orchard 1.10. The goal is to obscure certain content from non-paying users while keeping its detail page accessible as a teaser.

The original idea was to use a `ShapeTableProvider` to inspect every "Content" shape and change its display type according to the permissions of the user. Then it would be possible to customize what we want to show in placement on a per-content basis. e.g. only display the Layout_Summary instead of the full Layout if users don't have access to a news article.

Something along these lines:

```
builder.Describe("Content").OnDisplaying(displaying => {
    if(displaying.Shape.Metadata.DisplayType == "Detail"  && !_authorizer.Authorize(ViewPaidContent) {
        displaying.Shape.Metadata.DisplayType == "DetailPaywall";      
    }
});
```

--

```
<Placement>
    <Match DisplayType="DetailPaywall">
        <Place Parts_Layout="-"/>
        ...
    </Match>  
</Placement>
```

However, it turns out that `OnDisplaying` happens too late, placement has already been decided and ContentDrivers get invoked. `OnCreated` happens too early and would be overridden again. I believe the relevant code that triggers these is the `BuildDisplay` method in `Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentDisplay`. Whichever `displayType` parameter is passed here is the one that ends up getting used.

Is there any way to influence display type in code based on some condition, or a different approach we can use to achieve similar functionality?

Comment: How about adding an alternate, rather than changing the display type? That's usually the way to go for those types of scenarios. Here's a link to an old sample along those lines (note this particular sample's scenario has been baked into the main product since, but the process remains the same in Orchard 1.x). If that works for you, I'll refactor this into a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display type is usually determined by the driver for the part. What you should probably do instead is introduce an alternate:

```
builder.Describe("Content").OnDisplaying(displaying => {
    if(displaying.Shape.Metadata.DisplayType == "Detail"  && !_authorizer.Authorize(ViewPaidContent) {
        displaying.Shape.Metadata.Alternates.Add("Content__Paywall");      
    }
});
```

You can then add a `Content-Paywall.cshtml` template override to your theme and you should be done.

Comment: The main reason I wanted to change the display type itself is so that I could use placement for granular control over what is/isn't shown for any particular content type. I solved this by simply having the alternate display its own content item again with the custom display type. Thanks for your time!

Comment: That said, I see a valid use case here for having an additional event fired between `Created` and `Displaying`. Adjusting the metadata on the fly would prevent the overhead of invoking some drivers twice.